# Get last foldername if folder has spaces with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, command

Using a batch file, I am trying to get the last foldername in a path.

The batch file gets the current working directory, goes up one level and uses that foldername. The problem is that if the foldername has spaces like "My Project", then the below code will return just "Project".

```
@echo off
cls

:: get pathnames
set ProjectRoot=%~dp0..\
set ProjectRootLast=%ProjectRoot:~0, -1%
for %%f in (%ProjectRootLast%) do (
    set ProjectName=%%~nxf
)

echo %ProjectRoot%
echo %ProjectName%
pause
```

Comment: Remove the space in the `~0, -1` portion... and put quotes around the expression enumerated by `for` (the one in between the `()` after `in`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aschipfl is right, you should use:

```
@echo off
cls

:: get pathnames
set "ProjectRoot=%~dp0..\"
set "ProjectRootLast=%ProjectRoot:~0,-1%"
for %%f in ("%ProjectRootLast%") do (
    set "ProjectName=%%~nxf"
)

echo %ProjectRoot%
echo %ProjectName%
pause
```

But you could do this much more efficiently using

```
for %%* in (.) do echo %%~nx*
```

to get the name of the current directory and

```
for %%* in (./..) do echo %%~nx*
```

To get the name of the directory above that